# Java POI Excel encoding - Debug vs Production

Tags: java, excel, encoding, apache-poi, translation

I'm writing a simple program that should translate an excel page from hebrew to english.
for doing this, the code reads every cell's content and compare it to a map that get the info from a simple csv file.
Running the program from IntelliJ, the program acts perfectly and does what it should, however compiling it to a jar, the program doesn't do that.

```
//Code for loading the csv contents to a map
private static Map<String,String> getLocalization(String pathToJar) {
    String path = null;
    path = pathToJar + "localization.csv";

    String line = "";
    HashMap<String, String> list = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // use comma as separator
            String[] array = line.split(",");
            list.put(array[0], array[1]);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return list;
}

//Code for loading an Excel file and translating it
private static boolean updateExcel(Map<String,String> translation, String filepath, String pathToJar) {
    String path = pathToJar + "temp\\week.xlsx";

    //Read Excel document first
    FileInputStream input_document = null;
    XSSFWorkbook my_xlsx_workbook = null;
    try {
        input_document = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
        // convert it into a POI object
        my_xlsx_workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(input_document);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Read excel sheet that needs to be updated
    XSSFSheet my_worksheet = null;
    if (my_xlsx_workbook != null) {
        my_worksheet = my_xlsx_workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    }


    for (Row cells : my_worksheet) {
        String name = "";
        String shortCode = "";

        //Get the row object
        Row row = cells;

        //Every row has columns, get the column iterator and iterate over them
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            //Get the Cell object
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
            //check the cell type and process accordingly
            switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case STRING:
                    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : translation.entrySet()) {
                        if (cell.getStringCellValue().contains(entry.getKey())) {
                            cell.setCellValue(entry.getValue());
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
    my_worksheet.autoSizeColumn(1);

    FileOutputStream outFile = null;
    try {
        if (input_document != null) {
            input_document.close();
        }
        File finishedFile = new File(path);
        outFile = new FileOutputStream(finishedFile);
        my_xlsx_workbook.write(outFile);
        outFile.close();

        finishedFile.renameTo(new File(filepath));
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```

The csv file looks something similar to:
hebrew_word,english_word
hebrew_word,english_word
hebrew_word,english_word
...

A few things I checked:
1. The map is being read from the file (tried encoding it to UTF-8)
2. IntelliJ's settings are set to UTF-8

I believe this is an encoding issue, outputting the keys of the map to the excel cells shows a bunch of special characters instead of the words.

If there is any other information needed please tell me, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileReader` is an old utility class, that uses the default platform encoding. Running in IntelliJ you said that was set to UTF-8 as is the encoding of the file. Outside IntelliJ it depends on the machine. Windows till now does not use UTF-8.

One can do it with `Files.lines` since java 8:

```
try {
    Path p = Paths.get(path);
    Files.lines(p)
        .map(line ->line.split(",\\s*"))
        .filter(array -> array.length >= 2)
        .forEach(array -> list.put(array[0], array[1]));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

`Files.lines` can be passed an Charset too, but the new default is UTF-8.